# How to create dataframe of output

Tags: python, urllib

I run a query to a webserver with certain added criteria.
I specify a date range which alters the date in the url.
I then pull the data line for specified symbols and I get a list of short volume etc. for the specified stock and time frame.
However, I want to be able to get the output as a dataframe.
The dataframe is now still the stored dataframe from the last ran url, and not of the output.

I tried to use list_.append which I did not get to work.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import urllib

symbols = ['AABA']

start_date = datetime(2019, 5, 10 )
end_date = datetime(2019, 5, 15 )

datelist = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=(end_date-start_date).days+1).tolist()

for date in datelist:
    url =  f"http://regsho.finra.org/FNYXshvol{date.strftime('%Y%m%d')}.txt"  

    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(url,delimiter='|')
        if any(df['Symbol'].isin(symbles)):
            stocks = df[df['Symbol'].isin(symbols)].to_string(index=False, header=False)
            print(stocks)
        else:
            print(f'No stock found for {date.date()}' )
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
         continue
```

The result is now:

```
20190510  AABA  2300.0  0.0  14617.0  N
20190513  AABA  2816.0  0.0  39128.0  N
20190514  AABA  1761.0  0.0  26191.0  N
20190515  AABA  24092.0  0.0  62745.0  N
```

I want the result to be in a dataframe so that I can directly export the result to csv

Answer (score 0):

Why do you convert dataframe to string when you want the output to be a dataframe? (For example, `df[df['Symbol'].isin(symbols)].to_csv('ABBA.csv', index=False, header=False)`) Anyways, to convert string back to dataframe you can use [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
from io import StringIO

df=pd.read_fwf(StringIO(stocks), header=None)
```

OUTPUT:

```
          0     1        2    3        4  5
0  20190510  AABA   2300.0  0.0  14617.0  N
1  20190513  AABA   2816.0  0.0  39128.0  N
2  20190514  AABA   1761.0  0.0  26191.0  N
3  20190515  AABA  24092.0  0.0  62745.0  N
```

Comment: Thanks Ricky. Any chance you are able to help me with the question I asked Serge Ballesta above?

Comment: @Leon Yes, there are few ways you can speed up the process. One of them would be instead of using `pd.read_csv`, you could use `open` instead

Answer (score 0):

`stocks` is a dataframe before you convert it to a string. Just keep it as a dataframe, store it in a list and just concat that list to obtain a full dataframe:

```
dflist = []
for date in datelist:
    url =  f"http://regsho.finra.org/FNYXshvol{date.strftime('%Y%m%d')}.txt"  

    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(url,delimiter='|')
        if any(df['Symbol'].isin(symbles)):
            stocks = df[df['Symbol'].isin(symbols)]
            print(stocks.to_string(index=False, header=False))
            dflist.append(stocks)
        else:
            print(f'No stock found for {date.date()}' )
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
         continue 

df = pd.concat(dflist)
```

Comment: Thanks, I indeed overlooked that I converted the already df back to string. If I could ask you another question: is there any way I can speed up the process? It now for example takes one second per day for a stock. Anyway to increase the reading time? I want to obtain data for 9 years which equal roughly 9 x 365 = 3285 seconds, which is 1 hour...